# Does this problem lead to an approach to hypothesis testing without memorizing test statistics?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I took an online probability course a while back and ran into a textbook example in which a bank needed to calculate what interest rate would yield a $1$% probability of taking a loss on the totality of money they loaned out due to defaults.  The interest rate was $2$% on $1000$ loans of $\$180000$ each with a loss of $\$200000$ per default.

Until recently, I believed this to be an example of hypothesis testing, due to several serious points of contact, and attempted to fit $Z$-testing problems into its solution framework, but it didn't seem to harmonize.  It's solution started with...$$Pr(S\ <\ 0)\ =\ .01$$...which led me to believe $S\ <\ 0$ was either the null or alternative hypothesis and $.01$ was the significance level.  Using algebra, it transformed the above to ...$$Pr(\frac{S - E[S]}{SE[S]}\ <\ \frac{-E[S]}{SE[S]})\ =\ .01$$...then observed that this means...$$\frac{-E[S]}{SE[S]}\ =\ qnorm(.01)$$...and plugged in all the appropriate expressions.  Just in case I left out any important details, the complete problem was...

[image]

In addition to the hypothesis and significance level, subtracting $E[S]$ and dividing by $SE[S]$ also seems related to the test statistic for $Z$-testing on a mean, as does consulting the Gaussian's Cumulative Distribution Function.

Am I correct that this is not quite the same as hypothesis testing?  Is it perhaps an inverse operation to $Z$-testing?  Does something like the above method provide a general way to derive the test statistic for at least some broader class of hypothesis testing problems (granted we may still need a general way to relate the standard error to the standard deviation to completely eliminate the need for memorization)?